# Request from external api(cordova) to Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, cordova, fetch-api

I need make a request from cordova to laravel api.

The code i use is:

```
await fetch('http://192.168.100.45:8000/reparacion/tareas/taller/crear/mobile', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({ 
     _token,
     *data*
   }),
})
```

I recover the token from database(atributte: remember_token).
The request have a 419 response. If i cancelled the verification(in VerifyCsrfToken.php file) of token working well.

Comment: The remember_token is the wrong token. That's for something else.

Comment: Routes in `routes/web.php` are protected by CSRF by default, so making an external request won't work unless you disable that (not recommended). Or, you can move this route to `routes/api.php`, and post to to `http://192.168.100.45:8000/api/reparacion/tareas/taller/crear/mobile` (notice the addition of `/api`).

Comment: @ceejayoz what's the correct token?

Comment: @LucianoPalacio The proper token is the one generated by `csrf_token()`. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token for examples of how to pass it over to the JavaScript side. `users.remember_token` is used in a cookie for the "remember me" login functionality; it's entirely separate.